# Help needed in understanding a example of complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, substitution

I was reading an example from the chapter complex numbers.
Here it is:

> Prove that
>   $${\sqrt{7\over2} }≤ |1 + z|+|1 − z + z^2| ≤ 3{\sqrt{7\over6}}$$
>   for all complex numbers with $|z| = 1$.

Now in the solution the author takes $|z+1|=t$. Hence giving the equation ${t^2-2\over2}=\operatorname{Re}(z)$.
Now in the next step author writes $|1 − z + z^2|=\sqrt{|7-2t^2|}$.
I don't get how this very step equation arises.

I tried it using $Z\bar{Z}=|Z|^2$ and got $|1 − z + z^2|=\sqrt{7-2t^2+z^2+\bar z^2}$.

Here is the calculation part:

> $|1 − z + z^2|=\sqrt{(1-z+z^2)(1-\bar z+\bar z^2)}$
>   $|1 − z + z^2|=\sqrt{1-z-\bar z+z^2+\bar z^2+z\bar z+z^2\bar z^2-z\bar z^2-\bar zz^2}$
>   $|1 − z + z^2|=\sqrt{3-2(z+\bar z)+z^2+\bar z^2}\Rightarrow \sqrt{7-2t^2+z^2+ \bar z^2}$  {using $z\bar z=1$}

Can't get it further. Am I doing right or wrong. Please help.

Comment: It might be worth showing the calculations that got you this different result. It might also be worth saying which book you're using.

Comment: @J.G. -I'm using Complex numbers from A to Z by Titu Andrescuu and Dorin Andrica.

Comment: For others' reference it's 1.1.7 Problem 5.

Comment: $|1-z+z^2|=|\bar z-1+z||z|=|2\text{Re}\,z-1|=|t^2-3|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $z\bar{z}=1\implies\bar{z}=1/z$
$$(1-z+z^2)(1-1/z+1/z^2)$$
$$=(z^2-z+1)^2/z^2$$
$$=(z^4-2z^3+3z^2-2z+1)/z^2$$
$$=(z+1/z)^2-2(z+1/z)+3$$
Now use $z^2+2z+1=zt$ to get
$$=(t^2-2)^2-2(t^2-2)+1$$
$$=(t^2-2)(t^2-4)+1$$

---

EDIT: Thanks to Dylan and Love Invariants for it!

I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. I thought you want help in proving what I showed earlier.

Note that the answer given in book, $\sqrt{7-2t^2}$ is incorrect. You can show this by simply taking $z=-1\implies t=|1+z|=|1-1|=0\implies |1-z+z^2|=\sqrt{7-2t^2}= \sqrt{7}$. Instead, $\sqrt{(t^2-2)(t^2-4)+1}=3$ gives the correct result, $|1-(-1)+1|=3$ ;)

Comment: Sir that part $7-2t^2$ is in modulus. Which means it is equal to $1$.

Comment: @LoveInvariants It's not true for $z=-1$ either way

Comment: @LoveInvariants If $z=-1$ then $t=0$, so you have $3 = \sqrt{7}$...

Comment: I've editted it

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the OP that $|1-z+z^2|^2=7-2t^2+z^2+\bar{z}^2$, but note that $$z^2+\bar{z}^2=(z+\bar{z})^2-2z\bar{z}=(t^2-2)^2-2=t^4-4t^2+2,$$so $$|1-z+z^2|^2=t^4-6t^2+9\implies |1-z+z^2|=|t^2-3|.$$It looks like the book's wrong.